# Get additional geolocation data (GnssStatus) in NativeScript application

Tags: geolocation, nativescript, android-gnss

In my NativeScript app I need to get additional geolocation info like **satellite count** or **satellite ids** which isn't provided by nativescript-geolocation plugin.

I am trying to use GnssStatus class from android.location in NativeScript app with the following:

```
const gnssCb = new android.location.GnssStatus.Callback();
```

After that I get an error:

`ERROR Error: JNI Exception occurred (SIGABRT)`

What am I doing wrong?
Or is there any alternative way I can get that info?

Comment: I guess you are missing the `onSatelliteStatusChanged` method implementation, try adding that.

Comment: @Manoj it would be great if you could provide a code snippet how to do this in NativeScript

Comment: Try `new android.location.GnssStatus.Callback({onSatelliteStatusChanged: function(status){}});`

Comment: Thanks for this snippet :). Unfortunately it didn't work for me: `cannot marshal javascript argument object object at index 0 to java type`

Answer (score 1):

`android.location.GnssStatus.Callback` is a class inherited from Object, so you may have to extend it to override the methods. I tested below code with Playground, it executes as expected.

```
class MyGnssStatus extends android.location.GnssStatus.Callback {
    constructor() {
      super();
      return global.__native(this);
    }

    onSatelliteStatusChanged(status) {

    }
  }
```

Comment: Looks good. Thanks for your answer! Not tested it yet. Will come back to this task soon to will leave the feedback here.